# how to change this js.erb to haml

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax

```
$('body').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'search_result2', :query => @result_query)) %>');
```

I want to use it in `.html.haml` with JavaScript,

```
$('body').replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'search_result2', :query => @result_query)) %>');
```

how to change this line

```
<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'search_result2', :query => @result_query)) %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
#{ escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'search_result2', :query => @result_query)) }
```

Comment: @Paul Fioravanti Yes...!!it's correct and very helpful..but I do not have enough reputation to vote up now.....:(